# Activities window is buggy after update to 22.04

Tags: graphics, 22.04

I had just updated to 22.04 from 20.04, and now activities look like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYVxZ.jpg

before updating to 22.04

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/613631693332545539/1005993480251773050/unknown.png

Using Nvidia driver version: 515.65.01

My kernel was and still is

Linux Mobile-Kep 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo lshw -C display returns

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104 [GeForce RTX 2080 Rev. A]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:133 memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff memory:4010000000-4011ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:81000000-8107ffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Which kernel stack were you using when on 20.04?  (GA=5.4 or HWE which likely meant you may have been already using 5.15? though not for long).  I see video issues (*graphics kernel module issue*), but what I see is of course colored by my own experiences which include [really] some old boxes which don't like newer kernels.  What modules (ie. *driver*) are you using? as maybe you'll have better choices (I'd likely look using `sudo lshw -C display` but there are many choices for your *unstated* graphics hardware).

Comment: Additional details should be added to your question; comments are for us to ask you questions (*with them being removed once details exist in your question*). You've still provided no details of your actual hardware (as kernel modules/drivers need to match hardware; the *unstated* detail in prior comment).  Which kernel stack were you using on 20.04? (ie. was your kernel changed when you switched from 20.04 where I gather you had no issues? or it remained the same?)